# Get the latest specific date prior to today

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the Google Analytics Add-On for Google Spreadsheets, and need to get data for the financial year to date. I have the finish date set as:

```
=TODAY()
```

Which is working fine. Now I need to have a start date that is the 6th of April prior to today. I can enter this manually, but was wondering if there was a way of doing it using a formula working backwards from `TODAY`?

Answer (score 1):

The following formula does this:

```
=if(date(year(today()), 4, 6) < today(), date(year(today()), 4, 6), date(year(today())-1, 4, 6))
```

It constructs `date(year(today()), 4, 6)`, which is the 6th of April of the current calendar year. If this date is prior to today, it is the output. Otherwise, the year is reduced by 1.